# purrr mapping not producing tidy data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Thanks to this site, I'm using the R `purrr` package to aggregation data based on multiple columns.  The aggregation is working how I want but the output is not.  Here is a sample using the `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
#pull in data
data <- mtcars
#get colnames
variable1 <- colnames(data)
#map the variables
t1 <- map(variable1, ~ data %>%
         group_by_at(.x) %>%
         summarize(number = mean(mpg))) %>%
    set_names(variable1) %>%
    bind_rows(., .id = 'variable')
```

Were I expect three columns (Predictor Variable, Levels within Each of those Variables, aggregation), I have 8.  See the image below:

[image: Output of above code]

How can I take my code up at the top and turn out a tidy dataset?

Comment: Maybe do a second `map` like `map(.f = gather,key = "var",value = "value",-number)`? As it is, you're bind things by rows with different columns, so it's not surprising that it would create new columns where they don't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to reshape your data to long form, which lets you aggregate with ordinary dplyr:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mpg_means <- mtcars %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -mpg) %>% 
    group_by(variable, value) %>% 
    summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))

mpg_means
#> # A tibble: 146 x 3
#> # Groups:   variable [?]
#>    variable value mean_mpg
#>    <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 am          0.     17.1
#>  2 am          1.     24.4
#>  3 carb        1.     25.3
#>  4 carb        2.     22.4
#>  5 carb        3.     16.3
#>  6 carb        4.     15.8
#>  7 carb        6.     19.7
#>  8 carb        8.     15.0
#>  9 cyl         4.     26.7
#> 10 cyl         6.     19.7
#> # ... with 136 more rows
```

Note that while `mtcars` is entirely numeric, if you have different types, converting to long form will coerce variable types. The calculations will be the same, but it may cause issues later. To resolve it, use an output format that can handle diverse types, e.g.

```r
mpg_means_in_list_cols <- mtcars %>% 
    as_tibble() %>%    # compact printing for list columns
    summarise_all(list) %>%    # collapse each column into a list of itself
    gather(group, group_values, -mpg) %>% 
    mutate(mpg_means = map2(mpg, group_values,    # for each mpg/value pair, ...
                            ~tibble(mpg = .x, group_value = .y) %>%    # ...reconstruct a data frame...
                                group_by(group_value) %>% 
                                summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))))    # ...and aggregate

mpg_means_in_list_cols
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    mpg        group group_values mpg_means        
#>    <list>     <chr> <list>       <list>           
#>  1 <dbl [32]> cyl   <dbl [32]>   <tibble [3 × 2]> 
#>  2 <dbl [32]> disp  <dbl [32]>   <tibble [27 × 2]>
#>  3 <dbl [32]> hp    <dbl [32]>   <tibble [22 × 2]>
#>  4 <dbl [32]> drat  <dbl [32]>   <tibble [22 × 2]>
#>  5 <dbl [32]> wt    <dbl [32]>   <tibble [29 × 2]>
#>  6 <dbl [32]> qsec  <dbl [32]>   <tibble [30 × 2]>
#>  7 <dbl [32]> vs    <dbl [32]>   <tibble [2 × 2]> 
#>  8 <dbl [32]> am    <dbl [32]>   <tibble [2 × 2]> 
#>  9 <dbl [32]> gear  <dbl [32]>   <tibble [3 × 2]> 
#> 10 <dbl [32]> carb  <dbl [32]>   <tibble [6 × 2]>
```

While this is decidedly not as pretty, it's capable of holding many types tidily. To extract the result above, just add `%>% unnest(mpg_means)`. As-is, grouping variables are each held in a list element of `group_values` and in aggregated form in the first column of each `mpg_means` tibble.

Comment: This approach would indeed be considerably simpler.. Clearly pays off to re-frame the problem sometimes! (+1)

Comment: This is awesome.  In my actual dataset, the column I'm summarising is still showing up as a variable.  I thought the `-mpg` in the `gather` statement was to ensure that it would not show up in the variable column?

Comment: `-mpg` is there so it doesn't get reshaped to long form (so it shouldn't be in the `variable`/`group` column), and thus gets repeated for each variable that is. It will stay in the data frame till you `summarise` with the the first approach, or otherwise drop that list column (e.g. by `unnest`ing something else) with the second.

Comment: So I have my equivalent to `-mpg` yet it's still in the variable/group column.This is all in your first code snippet at the top.

Comment: Then `gather` isn't being called correctly somehow. At that point, there should be columns for `mpg`, `variable`, and `value`. Since `gather` won't both gather and leave a column, the column is probably being gathered when it shouldn't be, likely because the column specification (`-mpg`) is insufficient somehow. Without seeing the data, it's hard to say why, but there are other ways to specify which columns to gather, e.g. `cyl:carb` for `mtcars`.

Answer (score 2):

When grouping your data within the `map`, you can rename the grouping variable to `"level"`, since those values will form the column containing the levels of the grouping variable in the final data set.

When you have mixed types of grouping variables (e.g. both numeric and character), you'll also need to coerce the grouping variable to character in order to be able to bind the results together.

With those additions, you should get what you expect. (You can also skip the `bind_rows` by using `map_df` instead of `map`, to save a little bit of code, like I've done below.)

```r
reprex::reprex_info()
#> Created by the reprex package v0.1.1.9000 on 2018-02-09

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

data <- iris
vars <- names(data)

set_names(vars) %>% 
  map_df(function(var) {
    var <- set_names(var, "level")
    data %>% 
      group_by_at(var) %>% 
      summarize_at("Sepal.Length", "mean") %>% 
      mutate_at("level", as.character)
  }, .id = "variable")
#> # A tibble: 126 x 3
#>        variable level Sepal.Length
#>           <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
#>  1 Sepal.Length   4.3          4.3
#>  2 Sepal.Length   4.4          4.4
#>  3 Sepal.Length   4.5          4.5
#>  4 Sepal.Length   4.6          4.6
#>  5 Sepal.Length   4.7          4.7
#>  6 Sepal.Length   4.8          4.8
#>  7 Sepal.Length   4.9          4.9
#>  8 Sepal.Length     5          5.0
#>  9 Sepal.Length   5.1          5.1
#> 10 Sepal.Length   5.2          5.2
#> # ... with 116 more rows
```

You could also wrap the process in a function, and allow multiple variables to summarise with multiple functions. You'd have to spend a moment to come up with an evocative name though (I cheated and just used `foo` here).

```r
foo <- function(data, vars, funs) {
  grps <- names(data)
  set_names(grps) %>% 
    map_df(function(grp) {
      grp <- set_names(grp, "level")
      data %>% 
        group_by_at(grp) %>% 
        summarize_at(vars, funs) %>% 
        mutate_at("level", as.character)
    }, .id = "variable")
}

foo(iris, vars(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width), funs(mean, sd))
#> # A tibble: 126 x 6
#>        variable level Sepal.Length_mean Sepal.Width_mean Sepal.Length_sd
#>           <chr> <chr>             <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>
#>  1 Sepal.Length   4.3               4.3         3.000000             NaN
#>  2 Sepal.Length   4.4               4.4         3.033333               0
#>  3 Sepal.Length   4.5               4.5         2.300000             NaN
#>  4 Sepal.Length   4.6               4.6         3.325000               0
#>  5 Sepal.Length   4.7               4.7         3.200000               0
#>  6 Sepal.Length   4.8               4.8         3.180000               0
#>  7 Sepal.Length   4.9               4.9         2.950000               0
#>  8 Sepal.Length     5               5.0         3.120000               0
#>  9 Sepal.Length   5.1               5.1         3.477778               0
#> 10 Sepal.Length   5.2               5.2         3.425000               0
#> # ... with 116 more rows, and 1 more variables: Sepal.Width_sd <dbl>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikko Marttila.  In my actual data set, some of the "levels" are integers and some are characters.  I get an error that states `error in bind_rows_(x, .id): Column "level" can't be converted from integer to character.`  My apologies as I didn't know this would happen or I would have changed my data set.

Comment: You can fix that by just coercing the group column to character within the `map`

Comment: I put `var <- set_names(as.character(var), "level")` and it states `Error in as.character(var): cannot coerce type "closure" to vector of type "character"`

Comment: Use `mutate_at("level", as.character)` after the `summarise`; I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank so much @Mikko Marttila